# How to search any word and highlight it without using button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have a search function that searches for all the words entered. the function will run if the search button is clicked, I have made a function for it in the code below. what I want is to do a search without using the button like live search. 
any ideas for that? thanks

```
<style>
 #search_para {
  color: grey;
 }
 .highlight {
   background-color: yellow;
 }
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="search_text">
  <input type="button" value="search" id="search">
</div>
<div id="inputText1">
   <ul>
        @Html.ActionLink("Form User", "Index", "User", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
        @Html.ActionLink("Form Role", "Index", "Role", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
        @Html.ActionLink("Form Transaction", "Index", "Transaction", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })        
   </ul>
</div>
<script>
     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
          var searchpara = document.getElementById("inputText1").innerHTML;
          searchpara = searchpara.toString();
          document.getElementById("search").onclick = function () { highlight_word(searchpara) };
                }, false);

     function highlight_word(searchpara) {
          var text = document.getElementById("search_text").value;
          if (text) {
                var pattern = new RegExp("(" + text + ")", "gi");
                var new_text = searchpara.replace(pattern, "<span class='highlight'>" + text + "</span>");
                document.getElementById("inputText1").innerHTML = new_text;
           }
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`onkeyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup)

It will look like

```
document.getElementById("search_text").onkeyup = function() {
  highlight_word(searchpara)
};
```

**Working demo**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var searchpara = document.getElementById("inputText1").innerHTML;
  searchpara = searchpara.toString();
  document.getElementById("search_text").onkeyup = function() {
    highlight_word(searchpara)
  };
}, false);

function highlight_word(searchpara) {
  var text = document.getElementById("search_text").value;
  if (text) {
    var pattern = new RegExp("(" + text + ")", "gi");
    var new_text = searchpara.replace(pattern, "<span class='highlight'>" + text + "</span>");
    document.getElementById("inputText1").innerHTML = new_text;
  }
}
```

```css
#search_para {
  color: grey;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="search_text">
</div>
<div id="inputText1">
  <ul>
    @Html.ActionLink("Form User", "Index", "User", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) @Html.ActionLink("Form Role", "Index", "Role", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) @Html.ActionLink("Form Transaction", "Index", "Transaction", null, new {
    @class = "btn btn-primary" })
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it's working, but when I enter "br" in the textbox it will display my code like <br>, <ul> . @Carsten Løvbo Andersen